# how to upload reels to facebook with graph api python

Tags: python, api, facebook-graph-api

```
import requests
import os
import json

Title ="ขอเต้นหน่อยจ่ะ"
title = Title
description = title
source = f"E:\movies\{Title}.mp4"
files = {'source': open(source, 'rb')}
file_size = os.path.getsize(source)
print("File Size is :", file_size, "bytes")

def Initialize():
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/{'PAGE_ID'}/video_reels?upload_phase=start"
    payload = {
        'access_token': access_token,
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data = payload)
    return r.json()["video_id"]


video_id=Initialize()
print(video_id)

def Upload(vidid, size, filedata):
    url = f"https://rupload.facebook.com/video-upload/v13.0/{vidid}"
    payloadUp = {
        'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + access_token,
        'offset': "0",
        'file_size': str(size),
    }

    print(payloadUp)
    r = requests.post(url, data=filedata, headers=payloadUp)
    return r.text
print(Upload())
```

I got this code from one user. from my search From testing I get error as follows

---> 19 return r.json()["video_id"]

KeyError: 'video_id'

Please help me find a solution to the problem.